# StreamController with Firestore

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to user a `StreamController` to control a `StreamBuilder` that gets data from a collection in `Firestore`. This will enable me to use a  `RefereshIndicator` so that when I pull down on the list, it refreshes/ fetches more data if there is any.

I used most of the information in this [article](https://blog.khophi.co/using-refreshindicator-with-flutter-streambuilder/). My current code is below

```
    class _Lists extends State<List> {
      StreamController _controller;
      final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

        @override
         void initState() {
        _controller = new StreamController();
         loadPosts();         
        super.initState();
        }

       Future fetchPost() async {
       return await . 
       Firestore.instance.collection(_locationState).snapshots();
        }

      Future<Null> _handleRefresh() async {
      count++;
      print(count);
       fetchPost().then((res) async {
       _controller.add(res);
       showSnack();
        return null;
      });
     }

      showSnack() {
      return scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
      content: Text('New content loaded'),
      ),
       );  
     }

      loadPosts() async {
      fetchPost().then((res) async {
       print(res.document);
       _controller.add(res);
      return res;
      });
      }


       @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   final topBar = AppBar(Title("List"));
   bottom: TabBar(
    indicatorColor: Colors.blueAccent,
    indicatorWeight: 3.0,
    //indicatorSize: 2.0,
    indicatorPadding:
        const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0, left: 47.0, right: 
    47.0),
    tabs: [
      Tab(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage("MyImage1"),
          width: 65.0,
          height: 65.0,
        ),
      ),
      Tab(
        child: Image(
          image: AssetImage("Image2"),
          width: 90.0,
          height: 90.0,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),

return DefaultTabController(
    length: 2,
    child: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        appBar: topBar,
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _controller.stream,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text(snapshot.error);
              }
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                List aList = new List();
                aList.clear();
                for (DocumentSnapshot _doc in snapshot.data.documents) {
                  Model _add = new Model.from(_doc);
                  aList.add(_add);
                }
                return TabBarView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RefreshIndicator(
                      onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: aList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Card(aList[index]);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.directions_transit),
                  ],
                );
              } else {
                return Container(
                    child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
              }
            })));
 }
}
}
```

The Problem I have with this is I keep getting the error

```
    flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY 
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building 
StreamBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state:
flutter: _StreamBuilderBaseState<dynamic, 
AsyncSnapshot<dynamic>>#53c04):
flutter: Class '_BroadcastStream<QuerySnapshot>' has no instance getter 'documents'.
flutter: Receiver: Instance of '_BroadcastStream<QuerySnapshot>'
flutter: Tried calling: documents
```

Any ideas on how to go about using the `StreamController` with data from `Firestore` ?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping a close eye on return types in your IDE will likely help avoid a lot of confusing issues like this. Unfortunately, that blog does not indicate any types for the API call, StreamController, or 'res' in the then statement. Having those types declared will help show what you are working with (at least it does for me in Android Studio). For example in my StreamBuilder with a stream from Firestore, I use `AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot` instead of just `AsyncSnapshot`. This allows the tools in Android Studio to tell me that `snapshot.data.documents` is the map from the `QuerySnapshot` class. If I don't add the extra type, I can't see that.

Here is an example of listening to the stream from the [Firestore Dart package](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cloud_firestore).

```
//Performing a query:

Firestore.instance
    .collection('talks')
    .where("topic", isEqualTo: "flutter")
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data: QuerySnapshot) =>
        // do stuff here
    );
```

Since you're using the async/await style (also perfectly fine), you'll have the same result that will be inside of `.listen((data) =>`. We can follow the documentation/classes to see what types are returned.

`Firestore.instance.collection(<whatever>).snapshots()`
will return
`Stream<QuerySnapshot>`,
so we know that
`await Firestore.instance.collection(<whatever>).snapshots()`
will return
`QuerySnapshot`.

Digging further into the class, we see it has a property called `documents`.

```
  /// Gets a list of all the documents included in this snapshot
  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents;
```

This finally gives us those `DocumentSnapshot`s, which you'll have to pull the `data` property from.

So in your case, I believe the `res` type being `QuerySnapshot` will help show you what data to put in your stream, which can be done multiple ways at this point. `List<DocumentSnapshot>` seems to look like what you're going for, but you could go farther to `List<YourClass>` built from the `DocumentSnapshot` `data` property. With that, you can say what data type your StreamController will return, making the builder's `AsyncSnapshot<your stream type>` much more clear to work with.

I'm not sure what development tools you are using, but in case you aren't familiar most will allow you to do something like: press/hold (command or ctrl), hover over the type/class/function/var you want to see, left click, and you should be taken to the source files/declarations (I find this super handy).